# Beginner tries to extend observable (unsuccessfully) and asks for advise

Tags: java, observable

I’m new in Java programming. Now I’m implementing interface of my project using `JavaFX` and I encountered different problems with observable values.
For example, I have class for my data

```
public class DataItem 
{
    public DataItem(String sNewName, int nNewValue ) {
        setName(sNewName);
        setValue(nNewValue);
    }

    public DataItem() {
        setName("");
        setValue(0);
    }

    private String sName;

    public String getName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public final void setName(String sNewValue) {
        sName = sNewValue;
    }

    private int nValue;

    public int getValue() {
        return nValue;
    }

    public final void setValue(int nNewValue) {
        nValue = nNewValue;
    }    

}
```

Also I have container that has pointer to my data item object. I need to listen weather it changes or not, so I extend `ObservableValueBase`:

```
class myProperty extends ObservableValueBase<String>
{
    DataItem value;

    public myProperty(String sInit, int nInit) {
        value  = new DataItem(sInit, nInit);
    }


    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value.getName() + "(" + 
                                        Integer.toString(value.getValue()) + 
                                    ")";
    }

    public void setData (String sN, int nV) {
        value.setName(sN);
        value.setValue(nV);

        fireValueChangedEvent();
    }

    public void setDataItem(DataItem di) {
        value = di;
        fireValueChangedEvent();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value.getName() + "(" + Integer.toString(value.getValue()) + ")";
    }

}
```

And finally I have list of such objects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoWithMyProp();
}

private static void DoWithMyProp() {
    List<myProperty> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new myProperty("myP", 1), new myProperty("myP", 2)));


    arrayList.add(new myProperty("myP", 3));


    ObservableList<myProperty> obLlist = FXCollections.observableList(arrayList, (myProperty myTreeData) -> {


                    System.out.printf("observableArrayList.Callback<>.call(%s)\n", myTreeData);

                    myTreeData.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

                        @Override
                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                            System.out.println("\t" + observable.getClass() + " has changed. Old: = " + oldValue + ", New = " + newValue);
                        }

                    });

                    return new Observable[] {
                        myTreeData,
                    };

    });


    obLlist.addListener(new ListChangeListener<myProperty>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends myProperty> c) 
        {

            System.out.printf("ListChangeListener.onChanged(%s). ", c.getClass());

            while (c.next()) 
            {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {System.out.println("c. Was Added:" + c);}
                if (c.wasUpdated()) {System.out.println("c. Was Updated: " + c);}
                if (c.wasPermutated()) {System.out.println("c. Was Permutated: " + c);}
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {System.out.println("c. Was Removed: " + c);}
            }
        }
    });


    myProperty mNew = new myProperty("add! myP", 4);
    arrayList.add(mNew);

    obLlist.stream().forEach(m -> System.out.println(m) );

    System.out.println("=========");

    obLlist.add(1, new myProperty("Wooh myP", 11)) ;
    obLlist.remove(2);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Item 2 set name");
    obLlist.get(2).setData("ch! myP", 12);

    System.out.println("Item 3 set property");
    DataItem di1 = new DataItem("add! myP extra", 5);
    obLlist.get(3).setDataItem(di1);


    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println();


    obLlist.stream().forEach(m -> System.out.println(m) );
}
```

It seems like it works well but I found that listener is not called when I set data item. I mean this line:

`obLlist.get(3).setDataItem(di1);`

Listener is not called despite of the fact that I call `fireValueChangedEvent()`.

What am I doing wrong? Is it correct to use `ObservableValueBase` in this case? Maybe you can recommend what I can read to understand observable and properties architecture better? Or examples of extending of properties and best practices?

I walking around Oracle docs like a blind man – it seems that I read all over there but I can’t understand common principle

Comment: Side note on code quality: read about java coding style; for example regarding naming of classes, variables.

Comment: Please see my [example](http://ideone.com/E3XguC)

Comment: I think it's not possible to bind it with the TableView or some other interface class.

Comment: What is your overall goal with this?

Comment: I have ‘TableView’ that represents list of objects that include string value and pointer on the object of other class. My string value is ‘SimpleStringProperty’ so it’s easy to react when it is changed somehow. But I don’t know how to manage reaction on pointer changing. I think that I need to extend ‘Property’ class to be able to add listener etc. But I’m too new in Java to implement all methods like ‘bind()’, ‘unbind()’, ‘addListener()’, ‘removeListener()‘ etc. So I’m looking for example or common principles explanation.